# How to make CMD program to not wait for an input C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to program wait for a span of 1 second for the user input, if there is none then do some part of code, otherwise break out of the loop, i have an example below:

```
while (true)
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
         Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an input");

         Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Input made");
}
```

The problem is, that after the input is made Console.KeyAvailable property is still in **true** value, so it will be outputting "Input made" forever, is there any alternative to Console.KeyAvailable or how do i make it work more that once?

Comment: Did you try doing one (or more) `Console.ReadKey()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the input buffer again with `Console.ReadKey(true)`.

```
while (true)
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
         Console.WriteLine("Waiting for an input");

         Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Input made");
    //If you dont need the key Info, you can also just write Console.ReadKey(true)
    var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```